# IIS URL Rewrite Default.aspx instead of Slash

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, seo

I'm using IIS's URL Rewrite and want for SEO purposes I want to rewrite all URLs that end with / to Default.aspx. Similar to this:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/20/tip-trick-fix-common-seo-problems-using-the-url-rewrite-extension.aspx

However, I can't find anywhere how to do proper rewrite as all articles do reverse thing - rewrite Default.aspx to /... the problem is that this messes up Postbacks - when you click ASP.NET button on the page you just get redirected to the same page.

Any ideas?

Comment: You're trying to rewrite all requests to `Default.aspx` to `/`? Can you not just set the default document for a folder in IIS to `Default.aspx`? No rewrite necessary. Or are you trying to setup a 301 redirect?

Comment: 301 redirect and I want to redirect / to Default.aspx (not the other way around)

Comment: Okay. Have you tried just `/$` for the pattern?

Comment: Nope... I suck when it comes to regular expressions... I'll give it a try and post rule if I succeed

Comment: `$` is "ends with" so hopefully that should match "end with forward slash".

Comment: The problem is how to match - http://website.com ;(

Comment: So a URL without a forward slash, just basically the domain? Those don't exist. Browsers automatically append a forward slash to empty requests (per RFC 2616 Section 3.2.2). The trailing slash can be omitted for sub folders, is that what you mean? If you have a folder off of root called `xyz` and you make a request for `/xyz` IIS will first check if there's a file that matches that pattern. If that fails it checks for a folder with that pattern. If found it 301 redirects to `/xyz/`. But at a higher level I'm really not understanding what problem you're having in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chris answered question in comments.